# Macro to fold-in %BEGIN_FOLD on opening file?

Tags: texstudio, code-folding

is there any way to get TeXstudio to always display all

```
%BEGIN_FOLD
...
%END_FOLD
```

blocks folded in when opening a file? Possibly using a macro?

Thanks a lot!

rmh

Comment: No this is not possible. The folding API is not exposed.